# How to implement nested loop with promise map

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have code like this:

```
Promise.all(venue.map(venue => {
    return Promise.all(concat_all.map(tgl => {
        pool.query("INSERT INTO peminjaman_venue VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            [id_event, venue, nama_lengkap_peminjam, jabatan_nim_peminjam, jumlah_personel,
                id_google_calendar, waktu_mulai_rutin, waktu_selesai_rutin, tgl,
                tgl, fasilitas_lain],
            function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
            })
    }))
}).then(
    req.flash('message_success', 'Berhasil mengajukan event'),
    res.redirect('/pengajuan_event'))
    .catch(
    req.flash('message_err', 'Gagal mengajukan event'),
    res.redirect('/pengajuan_event')
    ))
```

The code returns error Can't set header after they are sent, that indicates the res.redirect() is called multiple times. But the code works. The data inserted to the db successfully. I changed the code below and the code just doesnt work at all.

```
Promise.all(venue.map(venue => {
    return Promise.all(concat_all.map(tgl => {
        pool.query("INSERT INTO peminjaman_venue VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            [id_event, venue, nama_lengkap_peminjam, jabatan_nim_peminjam, jumlah_personel,
                id_google_calendar, waktu_mulai_rutin, waktu_selesai_rutin, tgl,
                tgl, fasilitas_lain],
            function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
            })
    }))
}).then(() = >{
    req.flash('message_success', 'Berhasil mengajukan event')
    res.redirect('/pengajuan_event'))
    }

    .catch((err) => {
    req.flash('message_err', 'Gagal mengajukan event')
    res.redirect('/pengajuan_event')
    }
    )
)
```

Comment: Which DB library are you using? Many require you to pass a callback **OR** receive a promise. It looks like you are expecting a promise while also passing a callback. Are you sure your lib supports that? Also, you need to return the promise from your `map()` callback. You're currently making an array of undefined values and passing it to `Promise.all`

Comment: You need to close `)` of `then` before `catch`

Comment: Why did you not respond to questions asked here two days ago?  As Mark_M asked, in order to use promises optimally with your `pool.query()` database call, we need to know what database it is so we can properly use the promise interface to that specific API call.

Comment: In addition, the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers are not written correctly.  You need to pass them a function reference, not a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array to hold all your async requests. So

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(async request 1);
promises.push(async request 2);
...

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
 // do something ...
})
```

I would also refactor the code a bit to use async/await to remove some of those brackets. It is hard to read with all those nested promises.